# Long Player movement script

Tags: c#, unity3d

All of this does just one thing. Move my player by finding the first finger that was used to touch the ship and drag it.

I have a few questions:

- The first thing is I have an embedded class of MotionState. At first glance it makes a lot of sense to start with that. I latter ended up not using it. How do I go about refactoring this part of the code to scrap it without breaking my code?
- My other question is on syntax. Further along down my code I have helper classes that use some variables. I've read that when you use variables with helper functions you should just declare those variables right above the function. Is that correct and am I using that methodology correctly?
- Finally if there is something you see that should be done another way because of some easier way to do things please let me know.

---

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
    [SerializeField] bool usingTouch;
    Vector3 force;
    ShipManager shipManager;
    float topSpeed = 20;

    public Canvas Canvas;
    DebugController dc;
    bool isBeingTouched = false;
    int beingTouchedByFingerNumber = -1;
    float zPos;
    float distFromCamera;

    MotionState motionState;
    enum MotionState {
        waiting,
        start,
        drag,
    }

    public void Start() {
        meshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        shipManager = GetComponent<ShipManager>();
        dc = Canvas.GetComponent<DebugController>();
        zPos = gameObject.transform.position.z;
        GameObject camera = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
        distFromCamera = transform.position.z - camera.transform.position.z;//Used for ScreenToWorldPoint()
    }

    public LayerMask touchInputMask;
    RaycastHit hit;
    void Update() {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
            foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, touchInputMask)) {
                GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
                if (recipient.tag == "Player" && !isBeingTouched) {
                    OnTouchEnter(touch);
                }
            }
        }
    }
        if (beingTouchedByFingerNumber != -1) {
            dc.ChangeText(7, "Touched by Phase: " + Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase.ToString());
            dc.ChangeText(8, motionState.ToString());
        }
        if (beingTouchedByFingerNumber != -1 && Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
            OnTouchUp();
        }
        HandleMovement();
    }

    private void HandleMovement() {
        switch (motionState) {
            case MotionState.start:
                break;
            case MotionState.drag:
                Vector2 v2 = (Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).position);
                handlePlayerDrag(v2);
                break;
            case MotionState.waiting:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public void FixedUpdate() {
        if (motionState == MotionState.waiting)
            handleVelocity();
    }

    private void OnTouchEnter(Touch touch) {
        beingTouchedByFingerNumber = touch.fingerId;
        isBeingTouched = true;
        shipManager.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        Vector2 v2 = Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).position;
        GetOffsetOfMouseFromShip(v2);
        motionState = MotionState.drag;
        meshRenderer.enabled = false;
    }

    public void OnTouchEnter() {
        isBeingTouched = true;
        shipManager.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        Vector2 v2 = Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).position;
        GetOffsetOfMouseFromShip(v2);
        motionState = MotionState.drag;
        meshRenderer.enabled = false;
    }

    public void OnTouchUp() {
        isBeingTouched = false;
        shipManager.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = false;
        handleForceAveraging();
        beingTouchedByFingerNumber = -1;
        motionState = MotionState.waiting;
        meshRenderer.enabled = true;
    }

    public void handlePlayerDrag(Vector2 v2) {
        float step = topSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        Vector3 moveTo = turnTouchInputToWorldPoint(v2);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(moveTo) + offset, step);
        force = moveTo - previousLocation;//Changes the force to be applied
        previousLocation = moveTo;
        forceAddedToVectorArray();
    }

    //Turns a Vector2 touchInput to a world point
    private Vector3 turnTouchInputToWorldPoint(Vector2 v2) {
        Vector3 v3;
        if (usingTouch) {
            v3 = new Vector3(v2.x, v2.y, distFromCamera);
        } else {
            v3 = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, gameObjectToScreenPoint.z);
        }
        return v3;
    }

    private void handleVelocity() {
        shipManager.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = force;
    }

    Vector3 gameObjectToScreenPoint;
    Vector3 previousLocation;
    Vector3 offset;
    public void GetOffsetOfMouseFromShip(Vector2 v2) {
        //This grabs the position of the object in the world and turns it into the postion on the screen
        gameObjectToScreenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        Vector3 v3;
        if (usingTouch) {
            v3 = new Vector3(v2.x, v2.y, gameObjectToScreenPoint.z);
        } else {
            v3 = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, gameObjectToScreenPoint.z);
        }
        //Sets the mouse pointers vector3
        previousLocation = v3;
        //Set offset of mouse and ship
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(previousLocation);
    }

    //Add the force to a vector array to get the average of force to later apply on release of the ship
    public Vector3[] forces = new Vector3[10];
    public Vector3 forceAverage = Vector3.zero;
    public int forcesArrayLocation = 0;
    private void forceAddedToVectorArray() {
        forces[forcesArrayLocation] = force;
        forcesArrayLocation++;
        if (forcesArrayLocation == forces.Length)
            forcesArrayLocation = 0;
    }

    private void handleForceAveraging() {
        for (int i = 0; i < forces.Length; i++) {
            forceAverage += forces[i];
        }
        forceAverage /= forces.Length;
        force = forceAverage;
        //Makes sure there isn't a ludicrous speed
        if (force.sqrMagnitude > topSpeed * topSpeed) {
            force = force.normalized * topSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first thing is I have an embedded class of MotionState. At first
>   glance it makes a lot of sense to start with that. I latter ended up
>   not using it. How do I go about refactoring this part of the code to
>   scrap it without breaking my code?

First, `MotionState` is not a `class` but an `enum`. Setting this aside, you say that you are not using it, but you have used it 7 times in the current code.

---

> My other question is on syntax. Further along down my code I have
>   helper classes that use some variables. I've read that when you use
>   variables with helper functions you should just declare those
>   variables right above the function. Is that correct and am I using
>   that methodology correctly?

These classes aren't contained in the question so it is a little bit hard to answer but I try it nevertheless.

You should always declare your variables as near as possible to their usage. If a variable is only used **in one** method it should be declared **inside** this method to give it the most limited scope.

---

> Finally if there is something you see that should be done another way
>   because of some easier way to do things please let me know.

- your indention is completely off. If you are using Visual Studio with the [C# key binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4942145/2655508), the default keyboard shortcuts are `Ctrl + E,D` to format the document or `Ctrl + E,F` to format the selected code.
- you should stick to the style you have choosen.
  Right now you have sometimes stated explicitly the scope of methods `private` sometimes you left it to `default` which also is `private`.
  Sometimes you use braces `{}` for single statement `if` sometimes you don't.

  I would like to encourage you to use them always which helps to make your code less error prone.
- Comments should describe **why** something is done in the way it is done. Let the code speak for itself **what** is done by using meaningful names for variables, methods and classes.
- Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing. Right now your are mixing `PascalCase` and `camelCase` casing for naming your methods.
- Shortening variable names like `DebugController dc;` reduces the readability of the code. You should avoid using abbreviations.
- you have some `public` variables in your class. This open up the class for beeing manipulated from the outside which can lead to unecpected behaviour.

  If you need to read the values from outside of the class you should turn them into properties with a `public` getter and a `private` setter.

Now let us dig into your code

> ```
> //Turns a Vector2 touchInput to a world point
> private Vector3 turnTouchInputToWorldPoint(Vector2 v2) {
>     Vector3 v3;
>     if (usingTouch) {
>         v3 = new Vector3(v2.x, v2.y, distFromCamera);
>     } else {
>         v3 = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, gameObjectToScreenPoint.z);
>     }
>     return v3;
> }
> ```

could be written like

```
private Vector3 TurnTouchInputToWorldPoint(Vector2 v2) {

    if (usingTouch) {
        return new Vector3(v2.x, v2.y, distFromCamera);
    } 

    return new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, gameObjectToScreenPoint.z);
}
```

btw, I just noticed you are using the [K&R](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) style for placing your braces instead of the [Allman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style) style. If this is written in your coding guidelines you should stick to it, if not it would be better to switch to `Allman` because most C# developer uses it. In this way a new developer can easier read your code.

---

> ```
> private void OnTouchEnter(Touch touch) {
>     beingTouchedByFingerNumber = touch.fingerId;
>     isBeingTouched = true;
>     shipManager.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
>     Vector2 v2 = Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).position;
>     GetOffsetOfMouseFromShip(v2);
>     motionState = MotionState.drag;
>     meshRenderer.enabled = false;
> }
>
> public void OnTouchEnter() {
>     isBeingTouched = true;
>     shipManager.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
>     Vector2 v2 = Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).position;
>     GetOffsetOfMouseFromShip(v2);
>     motionState = MotionState.drag;
>     meshRenderer.enabled = false;
> }
> ```

Here the first method could be made smaller by calling the second method after using the `Touch` parameter like so

```
private void OnTouchEnter(Touch touch) {
    beingTouchedByFingerNumber = touch.fingerId;
    OnTouchEnter();
}
```

---

> ```
> private void HandleMovement() {
>     switch (motionState) {
>         case MotionState.start:
>             break;
>         case MotionState.drag:
>             Vector2 v2 = (Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).position);
>             handlePlayerDrag(v2);
>             break;
>         case MotionState.waiting:
>             break;
>         default:
>             break;
>     }
> }
> ```

by replacing the switch with a simple `if` like so

```
private void HandleMovement() {
    if (motionState != MotionState.drag) { return; }

    Vector2 v2 = (Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).position);
    handlePlayerDrag(v2);
}
```

the code can be reduced a lot.

---

> ```
> public LayerMask touchInputMask;
> RaycastHit hit;
> void Update() {
>     if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
>         foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches) {
>             Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
>
>         if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, touchInputMask)) {
>             GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
>             if (recipient.tag == "Player" && !isBeingTouched) {
>                 OnTouchEnter(touch);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
>     if (beingTouchedByFingerNumber != -1) {
>         dc.ChangeText(7, "Touched by Phase: " + Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase.ToString());
>         dc.ChangeText(8, motionState.ToString());
>     }
>     if (beingTouchedByFingerNumber != -1 && Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) {
>         OnTouchUp();
>     }
>     HandleMovement();
> }
> ```

this is a mess in the meaning of indention, so let us first fix it like so

```
public LayerMask touchInputMask;
RaycastHit hit;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, touchInputMask))
            {
                GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
                if (recipient.tag == "Player" && !isBeingTouched)
                {
                    OnTouchEnter(touch);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (beingTouchedByFingerNumber != -1)
    {
        dc.ChangeText(7, "Touched by Phase: " + Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase.ToString());
        dc.ChangeText(8, motionState.ToString());
    }
    if (beingTouchedByFingerNumber != -1 && Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        OnTouchUp();
    }
    HandleMovement();
}
```

as you will see it now uses the `Allman` style, because thats how my IDE is configured.

These `if` statements should be grouped together, so you don't need to check twice for `beingTouchedByFingerNumber` like so

```
    if (beingTouchedByFingerNumber != -1)
    {
        dc.ChangeText(7, "Touched by Phase: " + Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase.ToString());
        dc.ChangeText(8, motionState.ToString());
        if (Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)) 
        {
            OnTouchUp();
        }
    }
```

If `Input.touchCount` is the same as the number of items in `Input.touches` you can refactor

> ```
>     if (Input.touchCount > 0)
>     {
>         foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
>         {
>             Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
>
>             if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, touchInputMask))
>             {
>                 GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
>                 if (recipient.tag == "Player" && !isBeingTouched)
>                 {
>                     OnTouchEnter(touch);
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

like so

```
foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
{
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);

    if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, touchInputMask)) { continue; }

    GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
    if (recipient.tag == "Player" && !isBeingTouched)
    {
        OnTouchEnter(touch);
    }
}
```

but wait, what should we do with these 2 variables outside of the method, which are only used inside of this method ?

The `public` one we will keep outside because I guess you have a reason for it. But the other should be declared as near as possible to its usage.

The method would then look like so

```
private void Update()
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (!Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, touchInputMask)) { continue; }

        GameObject recipient = hit.transform.gameObject;
        if (recipient.tag == "Player" && !isBeingTouched)
        {
            OnTouchEnter(touch);
        }
    }

    if (beingTouchedByFingerNumber != -1)
    {
        dc.ChangeText(7, "Touched by Phase: " + Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase.ToString());
        dc.ChangeText(8, motionState.ToString());
        if (Input.GetTouch(beingTouchedByFingerNumber).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)) 
        {
            OnTouchUp();
        }
    }  

    HandleMovement();

}
```

---

Finished for now, leaving the remaining for you.

Comment: Public fields are required in Unity3D for the inspector to properly serialize them. There is a [SerializeField] attribute which also works, but this is an uncommon solution.

Comment: The Visual Studio shortcut chord on all of my installations (by default) is `CTRL` + `K`, `CTRL` + `D`.

Comment: @Heslacher 2012 Ultimate, 2013 Ultimate, and 2015 Enterprise RC.

Comment: Seems it depends on the key bindings. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4942145/2655508

Comment: @Heslacher Aha, perhaps you should include that in this answer as well?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: For the foreach section of code in the Update method why do you use contine? Is it to avoid another layer indenting of the bracketed code?

Comment: Exactly. Saving horizontal spacing.